# Can Polar Codes (or any other efficient codes) reach the second order capacity?

Tags: it.information-theory

In channel coding, it is known (e.g. [Yury Polyanskiy's thesis](http://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/thesis.pdf), and the arxiv article [A Tight Upper Bound for the Third-Order Asymptotics of Discrete Memoryless Channels](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3689)) that certain codes, for example polar codes, can reach the Shannon limit for large enough block lengths $n$. However, for finite $n$, the best theoretically possible codes are known to satisfy

$$\log M \leq n C - \sqrt{n V}\, \Phi^{-1}(1-ε) + \frac{1}{2} \log n + O(1),$$

where $M$ is the size of the code, $C$ the capacity of the channel, $V$ the dispersion of the channel, and $ε$ the required (average or maximum) error.

Is it known how Polar codes (or any other codes) compare to this fundamental bound? The bound can be achieved using random codes, but I was wondering if there are any efficient codes that come close.

Comment: Could you give references for each statement "it is known"? This way your question could, in addition to reach specialists of the field, also teach something to non-specialists of the field finding your question through search engines.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeremy. The reference for the fact that polar codes reach capacity is given in the comments of the answer below. A good reference for the bound on the logarithm of the code size is Yuri Polyanskiy's PhD thesis, which he provides on his [homepage](http://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/). We also did some work on this, showing that the logarithmic term does not exceed $\frac{1}{2} \log n$ for arbitrary discrete memoryless channels. This is on the [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3689).

Comment: Thanks! I added the links in the question for better clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, people conjecture that for Polar codes and any fixed DMBSC (discrete memoryless binary symmetric channel), $\log M \leq nC - O(n^{1-c})$ for some absolute constant $c > 0$ and vanishing error probability should be possible (or in other words, in order to be $\epsilon$ close to capacity, only a polynomially large $n$ in $1/\epsilon$ would suffice. However, there is no rigorous published proof available at this point. There are rumors about an upcoming proof, but that's not official yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So do I assume correctly that for other families of codes even less is known?

Comment: In terms of provable finite length guarantees for general memoryless channels, yes. Except for Forney/Justesen's concatenated codes which are capacity achieving but are known to require $n = exp(1/\epsilon)$ to be $\epsilon$-close to capacity.

Comment: *Update*. The rumored result "Polar Codes: Speed of polarization and polynomial gap to capacity" by Guruswami and Xia is now available, which hopefully answers your question: http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2013/050/

Comment: @MCH: That was fast :) Maybe you should update your answer rather than append a comment to it?